# Android fastest way to find the average color in triangle

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have bitmap and triangles some of which change vertices in real time, each triangle contains a value of the average color inside that same triangle. But generating the average color in a triangle is costly operation, that is why I need to generate average color only for those triangle that change at least one vertex, and use the previously generated colors for all triangles that do not change vertices.

If we have the triangles **▲ACD, ▲ABC and ▲BEC** and I found there corresponding colors: **green, blue, red**. Then vertex **E** changes position and new triangle pop-up ▲CED, so I need to generate its average color, but since the existing triangle ▲BEC is also change it need to generate its average color too. That mean triangles **▲ACD and ▲ABC** can use the previously generated color since there vertex coordinates are not changed.

What is the fastest way to get the previously generated colors for triangles that does not change vertices. Triangles are generated with [Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), so triangles order changes, that means first we can have an array [ACD, ABC, BEC] and after vertex E changes position we can have array [CED, BEC, ABC, ACD].

If I have 2000 triangles and 3 triangles change there vertices, so the rest 1997 triangles can use there previously generated colors. I have the vertices coordinates for each triangle and also there corresponding colors. If I check each of those 1997 triangle with each of the previous 2000 triangle(triangles that contains the previously generated colors) to determine if triangles match and get the corresponding color that is **~1997*2000 = ~3,994,000** total **if** checks in order to determine the previously generated colors for each triangle.

That is big amount of operations that need to be done in real time. Is there any way I can speed thing up, using something like HashMaps, where I can use the pair **coordinates as key**, and **color as value** or some other way?

[image]

To generate the Delaunay Triangulation from points I use this [library](https://github.com/slaviboy/VoronoiFloat). It keeps the points in the array **points**, and the triangle indices in the array **triangles**. That means to get the triangle coordinates I create extension fucntion with the following code:

```
fun Delaunay.getTriangleCoordinates(): FloatArray {

        val coordinates = FloatArray(triangles.size * 2)
        for (i in 0 until triangles.size / 3) {

            // get triangle points(vertices) indices
            val t0 = triangles[i * 3]
            val t1 = triangles[i * 3 + 1]
            val t2 = triangles[i * 3 + 2]

            // vertex 1
            coordinates[i * 6 + 0] = points[t0].x
            coordinates[i * 6 + 1] = points[t0].y

            // vertex 2
            coordinates[i * 6 + 2] = points[t1].x
            coordinates[i * 6 + 3] = points[t1].y

            // vertex 3
            coordinates[i * 6 + 4] = points[t2].x
            coordinates[i * 6 + 5] = points[t2].y
        }
        return coordinates
    }
```

In order to check only one value and not all vertices of a particular triangle, we can get the center of each triangle and use it as key point. It is demonstrated in the code below, again using extension function:

```
fun Delaunay.getTriangleCenterCoordinates(): FloatArray {

        val coordinates = FloatArray((triangles.size / 3) * 2)

        for (i in 0 until triangles.size / 3) {

            val t0 = triangles[i * 3]
            val t1 = triangles[i * 3 + 1]
            val t2 = triangles[i * 3 + 2]

            coordinates[i * 2] = (points[t0].x + points[t1].x + points[t2].x) / 3
            coordinates[i * 2 + 1] = (points[t0].y + points[t1].y + points[t2].y) / 3
        }
        return coordinates
    }
```

In order to draw the triangle with OpenGL I need all triangle coordinates as FloatArray, just what we get with **getTriangleCoordinates()**. I also need the corresponding color for each triangle as IntArray().

Here is the code that gets the average color for triangle with changed vertices or use the previously generated color for triangles with unchanged vertices.

```
var previousTriangleColors = IntArray(0)
var previousTriangleCenterCoordinates = FloatArray(0)

fun renderDelaunay() {

        // at least three points acquired
        if (delaunayPoints.size >= 3) {

            delaunay = Delaunay(delaunayPoints)

            val triangleCoordinate = delaunay.getTriangleCoordinates()
            val triangleCenterCoordinate = delaunay.getTriangleCenterCoordinates()

            val colors = IntArray(triangleCenterCoordinate.size / 2)
            for (i in 0 until triangleCenterCoordinate.size / 2) {

                // check if triangle vertices are changed or not
                var foundIndex = -1
                for (j in 0 until previousTriangleCenterCoordinates.size / 2) {
                    if (triangleCenterCoordinate[i * 2] == previousTriangleCenterCoordinates[j * 2] &&
                        triangleCenterCoordinate[i * 2 + 1] == previousTriangleCenterCoordinates[j * 2 + 1]
                    ) {
                        foundIndex = j
                        break
                    }
                }


                if (foundIndex != -1) {
                    // if triangle center is NOT changed, then use previously generated color
                    colors[i] = previousTriangleColors[foundIndex]
                } else {

                    // if triangle center is changed, then generate new average color

                    // first triangle vertex
                    val x1 = getImageGraphicCoordinateX(triangleCoordinate[i * 6])
                    val y1 = getImageGraphicCoordinateY(triangleCoordinate[i * 6 + 1])

                    // second triangle vertex
                    val x2 = getImageGraphicCoordinateX(triangleCoordinate[i * 6 + 2])
                    val y2 = getImageGraphicCoordinateY(triangleCoordinate[i * 6 + 3])

                    // third triangle vertex
                    val x3 = getImageGraphicCoordinateX(triangleCoordinate[i * 6 + 4])
                    val y3 = getImageGraphicCoordinateY(triangleCoordinate[i * 6 + 5])

                    // generate new average color for the triangle
                    colors[i] = averageColor(x1.toFloat(), y1.toFloat(), x2.toFloat(), y2.toFloat(), x3.toFloat(), y3.toFloat())
                }
            }
            previousTriangleColors = colors
            previousTriangleCenterCoordinates = triangleCenterCoordinate
        }
    }
```

Those two nested for loops works well on emulator, but are slow on actual android device, since it use costly operations. For example if the bitmap is with highly resolution 4096x4096, that means each triangle will have big area that will be used to generate the average color. And if I have 5000 triangles, with the two nested for loop we get ~5000x5000= 25,000,000 *if* checks, to see if triangle vertices coordinates are changed or not. I can reduce the bitmap size, and reduce the area that is used to generate the average color, but that is not the point. Since more than 98% of the triangles are not changed when single vertex is changed in real time, we can use the previously generated colors, but those two nested loops are the reason the app experience lagging. So I need a better way to check if triangle coordinates are changed.

Comment: this is an extremely interesting question and i'm not voting to close or saying it's bad, however, i think your question _might_ be a bit broad as it currently stands, because you don't have any code included. seeing as though hashmaps are available, have you tried a solution with a hashmap ? perhaps try to focus your question around your attempted solution with hashmaps and include what you've tried

Comment: If a vertex is changed, only the triangles connected to it change. Would it be possible to have a `Map<Vertex, List<Triangle>>` where each vertex is mapped to a list of the triangles it is part of? So you can just recompute the colors for the triangles in that list. Not sure how that would be play out with how you're generating triangles.